# How to open a CSV file inJupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, jupyter-notebook

I want to include an CSV file from my local computer into Jupyter Notebook using Pandas but every time I get a file not found error.

I tried including file using different directories as well as using r as before the file path.

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\shrey\Desktop\MINDTREE.csv')
```

```
The error message I am getting is the following:
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-23-d0297c50883f> in <module>()
    ----> 1 df=pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\shrey\Desktop\MINDTREE.csv')

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, doublequote, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
        676                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
        677 
    --> 678         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
        679 
        680     parser_f.__name__ = name

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
        438 
        439     # Create the parser.
    --> 440     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
        441 
        442     if chunksize or iterator:

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
        785             self.options['has_index_names'] = kwds['has_index_names']
        786 
    --> 787         self._make_engine(self.engine)
        788 
        789     def close(self):

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
       1012     def _make_engine(self, engine='c'):
       1013         if engine == 'c':
    -> 1014             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
       1015         else:
       1016             if engine == 'python':

    /opt/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
       1706         kwds['usecols'] = self.usecols
       1707 
    -> 1708         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
       1709 
       1710         passed_names = self.names is None

    pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

    pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

    FileNotFoundError: File b'C:\\Users\\shrey\\Desktop\\MINDTREE.csv' does not exist
```

Comment: Re-check the file name and path.

Comment: f=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/shrey/Desktop/MINDTREE.csv') try this

Answer (score 0):

'\' is an escape character in python and windows uses them to separate paths.

Try using:

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\shrey\\Desktop\\MINDTREE.csv')
```

or

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:/Users/shrey/Desktop/MINDTREE.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either put the csv in the directory where your jupyter notebook is saved or just use pandas `read_csv`

```
df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\shrey\\Desktop\\MINDTREE.csv')
```